# Split a string and pick the uppercase substring

Tags: string, bash, split, zsh, uppercase

Consider the following example variables in bash:

```
PET="cat/DOG/hamster"

FOOD="soup/soup/PIZZA"

SUBJECT="MATH/physics/biology"
```

How can I split any of those strings by a slash, extract the part that's all uppercase and store it in a variable? For example, how would I take `DOG` out of the `$PET` variable and store it in an `$OPTION` variable?

I need a portable solution that works under bash and zsh specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `tr` to remove all characters that are not uppercase:

```
OPTION=$(tr -dc '[:upper:]' <<< $PET)
```

Note that [here-strings](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html) (`<<< $VARIABLE`) are a `bash`-ism. In other shells you'll have to `echo` the variable into `tr`:

```
OPTION=$(echo "$PET" | tr -dc '[:upper:]')
```

Comment: Will fail for words in title case. e.g. `PET='Cat/DOG/Angus'`

Comment: True. However, judging from the examples the OP provided that doesn't seem to be an issue here.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Indeed, words in title case is not an issue here and the solution seems to work.

Comment: I should point out that this does not work in the older Bourne shell (sh). I got it working using `OPTION=$(echo $PET | tr -dc '[:upper:]')`.

Comment: Right cause they don't support HERE-STRING notation. That's bash only.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this -

```
OPTION=$(gawk -F'/' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /\<[A-Z]+\>/) print $i}' <<< $PET)
```

If you like a pure `bash` solution then you can add following piece of code

```
#!/bin/bash

PET="cat/DOG/hamster"
IFSBK=$IFS
IFS='/'
for word in $PET; do
    if [[ $word =~ [A-Z]+ ]]; then
        OPTION="$word"
    fi
done
IFS=$IFSBK
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Did you mean to type `awk` instead of `gawk`? The latter doesn't seem to be a valid command on my system. Additionally, upon trying to echo `$OPTION` it doesn't seem to output anything.

Comment: @faviouz It shouldn't matter. `gawk` is the `gnu extension` of `awk`. It has some neat features but nothing that should affect the above answer.

Comment: @Jaypal, yes `\<` is GNU specific

Comment: @sch Good catch. It should work if we use `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like there is only one portion of the string is in uppercase, so you can ignore the splitting portion of the question. This should work in both `zsh` and `bash` (although it is not portable in the sense of POSIX compatibility):

```
$ echo "${PET//[^A-Z]}"
DOG
```